# How to insert dynamic column name in C# SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql

I tried to insert a dynamic column name into my c# query string as follows.

```
"select @columnname from table"

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnname", obj.ColumnName);
```

but I could not get the desired result. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You **cannot** parametrize database object names - like schema, tables, columns - only **values**

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that?

Comment: you can try building query, e.g. `$"select {obj.ColumnName} from table"`

Comment: @marc_s since you cannot parametirize those, it probably means that you will have to use interpolated string in cases when column name, for example, is dynamic? And if yes, does it mean that you query will become vulnerable to injection attacks?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko $"select {obj.ColumnName} from table" is this approach not vulnerabale to sql injection attack?

Comment: @Mykhailo Seniutovych: we can't pass *field name* as a parameter, that's why we have to use formatting, string interpolation etc/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parametrize column names directly; however, you can select a column with a [CASE statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

```
SELECT CASE @columnname WHEN 'aaa' THEN aaa
                        WHEN 'bbb' THEN bbb
                        WHEN 'ccc' THEN ccc
       END AS TheColumn
FROM table
```